# module ABI major version (12) doesn't match the server's version (11)

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, xorg, xserver

I am trying to run the x server with ubuntu12.04 system .
I have updated all packages .
But when I am trying to execute x server command then ,I am getting below errors :

```
1) module ABI major version (12) doesn't match the server's version (11)
2) Failed to load module "pvr" (module requirement mismatch, 0)
3) FBDEV(0): Failed to allocate shadow framebuffer
```

PFB my xserver log file:

```
[  1140.525]
X.Org X Server 1.11.3
Release Date: 2011-12-16
[  1140.525] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[  1140.525] Build Operating System: Linux 2.6.42-51-highbank armv7l Ubuntu
[  1140.525] Current Operating System: Linux localhost.localdomain 2.6.37 #1 Tue
 Jul 8 16:49:39 IST 2014 armv7l
[  1140.525] Kernel command line: console=ttyO0,115200n8 noinitrd rw ethaddr=10.
60.4.222 ip=dhcp root=/dev/nfs nfsroot=10.60.4.135:/home/ppc/Downloads/armel_ubu
ntu,nolock, mem=128M vram=50M ti814xfb.vram=0:48M,1:1M,2:1M notifyk.vpssm3_sva=0
xA0000000 omapdss.def_disp="hdmi"
[  1140.533] Build Date: 16 October 2013  04:40:01PM
[  1140.534] xorg-server 2:1.11.4-0ubuntu10.14 (For technical support please see
 http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
[  1140.534] Current version of pixman: 0.30.2
[  1140.534]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
        to make sure that you have the latest version.
[  1140.534] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
        (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
        (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[  1140.547] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Thu Jan  1 00:19:00 197
0
[  1140.555] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[  1140.560] (==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.
[  1140.560] (==) No screen section available. Using defaults.
[  1140.560] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen Section" (0)
[  1140.560] (**) |   |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"
[  1140.562] (==) No monitor specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
        Using a default monitor configuration.
[  1140.562] (==) Automatically adding devices
[  1140.562] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[  1140.563] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[  1140.563]    Entry deleted from font path.
[  1140.563] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/" does not exist.
[  1140.563]    Entry deleted from font path.
[  1140.564] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not exist.
[  1140.564]    Entry deleted from font path.
[  1140.564] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi" does not exist.
[  1140.565]    Entry deleted from font path.
[  1140.565] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not exist.
[  1140.565]    Entry deleted from font path.
[  1140.565] (WW) The directory "/var/lib/defoma/x-ttcidfont-conf.d/dirs/TrueTyp
e" does not exist.
[  1140.566]    Entry deleted from font path.
[  1140.566] (==) FontPath set to:
        /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
        /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
        built-ins
[  1140.566] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabi/xorg/extra-modul
es,/usr/lib/xorg/extra-modules,/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[  1140.566] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices
.
        If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevic
es.
[  1140.566] (II) Loader magic: 0x40159d00
[  1140.566] (II) Module ABI versions:
[  1140.566]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[  1140.566]    X.Org Video Driver: 11.0
[  1140.566]    X.Org XInput driver : 16.0
[  1140.566]    X.Org Server Extension : 6.0
[  1140.566] (II) LoadModule: "extmod"
[  1140.576] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libextmod.so
[  1140.585] (II) Module extmod: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  1140.585]    compiled for 1.11.3, module version = 1.0.0
[  1140.585]    Module class: X.Org Server Extension
[  1140.585]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 6.0
[  1140.585] (II) Loading extension MIT-SCREEN-SAVER
[  1140.585] (II) Loading extension XFree86-VidModeExtension
[  1140.585] (II) Loading extension XFree86-DGA
[  1140.585] (II) Loading extension DPMS
[  1140.585] (II) Loading extension XVideo
[  1140.585] (II) Loading extension XVideo-MotionCompensation
[  1140.585] (II) Loading extension X-Resource
[  1140.585] (II) LoadModule: "dbe"
[  1140.587] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libdbe.so
[  1140.590] (II) Module dbe: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  1140.590]    compiled for 1.11.3, module version = 1.0.0
[  1140.590]    Module class: X.Org Server Extension
[  1140.591]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 6.0
[  1140.591] (II) Loading extension DOUBLE-BUFFER
[  1140.591] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[  1140.593] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[  1140.616] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  1140.616]    compiled for 1.11.3, module version = 1.0.0
[  1140.616]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 6.0
[  1140.616] (==) AIGLX enabled
[  1140.616] (II) Loading extension GLX
[  1140.616] (II) LoadModule: "record"
[  1140.618] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/librecord.so
[  1140.622] (II) Module record: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  1140.622]    compiled for 1.11.3, module version = 1.13.0
[  1140.622]    Module class: X.Org Server Extension
[  1140.622]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 6.0
[  1140.622] (II) Loading extension RECORD
[  1140.622] (II) LoadModule: "dri"
[  1140.624] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libdri.so
[  1140.630] (II) Module dri: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  1140.630]    compiled for 1.11.3, module version = 1.0.0
[  1140.630]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 6.0
[  1140.630] (II) Loading extension XFree86-DRI
[  1140.630] (II) LoadModule: "dri2"
[  1140.632] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libdri2.so
[  1140.635] (II) Module dri2: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  1140.635]    compiled for 1.11.3, module version = 1.2.0
[  1140.635]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 6.0
[  1140.636] (II) Loading extension DRI2
[  1140.636] (==) Matched pvr as autoconfigured driver 0
[  1140.636] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 1
[  1140.636] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[  1140.636] (II) LoadModule: "pvr"
[  1140.641] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/pvr_drv.so
[  1140.751] (II) Module PVR: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  1140.751]    compiled for 1.12.0, module version = 110.235.9475
[  1140.751]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[  1140.752]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 12.0
[  1140.752] (EE) module ABI major version (12) doesn't match the server's version (11)
[  1140.752] (II) UnloadModule: "pvr"
[  1140.752] (II) Unloading pvr
[  1140.752] (EE) Failed to load module "pvr" (module requirement mismatch, 0)
[  1140.752] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[  1140.755] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
[  1140.759] (II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  1140.759]    compiled for 1.11.3, module version = 0.4.2
[  1140.759]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 11.0
[  1140.759] (==) Matched pvr as autoconfigured driver 0
[  1140.759] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 1
[  1140.759] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[  1140.759] (II) LoadModule: "pvr"
[  1140.763] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/pvr_drv.so
[  1140.763] (II) Module PVR: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  1140.763]    compiled for 1.12.0, module version = 110.235.9475
[  1140.763]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[  1140.763]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 12.0
[  1140.763] (EE) module ABI major version (12) doesn't match the server's version (11)
[  1140.763] (II) UnloadModule: "pvr"
[  1140.763] (II) Unloading pvr
[  1140.763] (EE) Failed to load module "pvr" (module requirement mismatch, 0)
[  1140.763] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[  1140.766] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
[  1140.766] (II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  1140.766]    compiled for 1.11.3, module version = 0.4.2
[  1140.766]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 11.0
[  1140.766] (II) UnloadModule: "fbdev"
[  1140.767] (II) Unloading fbdev
[  1140.767] (II) Failed to load module "fbdev" (already loaded, 0)
[  1140.767] (II) FBDEV: driver for framebuffer: fbdev
[  1140.767] (--) using VT number 8

[  1140.767] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fbdev
[  1140.768] (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
[  1140.768] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
[  1140.771] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
[  1140.774] (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  1140.774]    compiled for 1.11.3, module version = 0.0.2
[  1140.774]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 11.0
[  1140.889] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
[  1140.889] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
[  1140.890] (II) FBDEV(0): using default device
[  1140.890] (WW) VGA arbiter: cannot open kernel arbiter, no multi-card support
[  1140.955] (II) FBDEV(0): Creating default Display subsection in Screen sectio
n
        "Default Screen Section" for depth/fbbpp 24/32
[  1140.955] (==) FBDEV(0): Depth 24, (==) framebuffer bpp 32
[  1140.955] (==) FBDEV(0): RGB weight 888
[  1140.955] (==) FBDEV(0): Default visual is TrueColor
[  1140.955] (==) FBDEV(0): Using gamma correction (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
[  1140.955] (II) FBDEV(0): hardware: ti81xxfb (video memory: 24576kB)
[  1140.955] (II) FBDEV(0): checking modes against framebuffer device...
[  1140.955] (II) FBDEV(0): checking modes against monitor...
[  1140.955] (--) FBDEV(0): Virtual size is 1920x1080 (pitch 1920)
[  1140.955] (**) FBDEV(0):  Built-in mode "current": 148.5 MHz, 67.5 kHz, 60.0
Hz
[  1140.955] (II) FBDEV(0): Modeline "current"x0.0  148.50  1920 2008 2052 2200
 1080 1084 1089 1125 -hsync -vsync -csync (67.5 kHz)
[  1140.955] (==) FBDEV(0): DPI set to (96, 96)
[  1140.955] (II) Loading sub module "fb"
[  1140.956] (II) LoadModule: "fb"
[  1140.959] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfb.so
[  1140.969] (II) Module fb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  1140.969]    compiled for 1.11.3, module version = 1.0.0
[  1140.969]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[  1140.969] (**) FBDEV(0): using shadow framebuffer
[  1140.969] (II) Loading sub module "shadow"
[  1140.969] (II) LoadModule: "shadow"
[  1140.973] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libshadow.so
[  1140.976] (II) Module shadow: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  1140.976]    compiled for 1.11.3, module version = 1.1.0
[  1140.976]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[  1140.976] (==) Depth 24 pixmap format is 32 bpp
[  1141.022] (EE) FBDEV(0): Failed to allocate shadow framebuffer
[  1141.022]
Fatal server error:
[  1141.022] AddScreen/ScreenInit failed for driver 0
[  1141.022]
[  1141.022]
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support
         at http://wiki.x.org
 for help.
[  1141.022] Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additio
nal information.
[  1141.022]
[  1141.024]  ddxSigGiveUp: Closing log
[  1141.024] Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
```

Can you please guide me in resolving this issue  ..

Tr,
Ashwin

Comment: I've run into this as well. I've asked the question here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/516039/xserver-error-ee-module-ani-major-version6-doesnt-match-the-servers-versi/516040?noredirect=1#comment700062_516040

Comment: have you got the final output .is x server is connecting now and can you see the output on your screen ?? I am runnnig my OpenCv example on TI DM8148 hardwrae .

Comment: No, apparently you need a live DVD/USB in order to fix the system files without altering the home directory.

Comment: Sorry to ask this question ,But what is the significance of having DVD/USB in order to fix this issue ..Can you elaborate this use  ??

Comment: You need to restore the system files corresponding to your ubuntu distro(mine is 14.04 now). This is due to the fact that Xserver(xorg package) is broken.

Comment: Can I just upgrade the x server instead of complete Ubuntu12.04 ??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59995/discussion-between-ashwin-and-sebi).